# How to find date of end of week in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I have the following date object in Ruby

```
Date.new(2009, 11, 19)
```

How would I find the next Friday?

Answer (score 13):

You could use end_of_week (AFAIK only available in Rails)

```
>> Date.new(2009, 11, 19).end_of_week - 2
=> Fri, 20 Nov 2009
```

But this might not work, depending what exactly you want. Another way could be to

```
>> d = Date.new(2009, 11, 19)
>> (d..(d+7)).find{|d| d.cwday == 5}
=> Fri, 20 Nov 2009
```

lets assume you want to have the next friday if d is already a friday:

```
>> d = Date.new(2009, 11, 20) # was friday
>> ((d+1)..(d+7)).find{|d| d.cwday == 5}
=> Fri, 27 Nov 2009
```

Comment: Well, `require activesupport` (after a suitable `gem install` of course) would be enough, I'd think.

Comment: Your first example would return yesterday, if the date happened to be a Saturday.

Comment: Yap, scott thats what I mean with 'dependening what you want that might not work'. It finds the friday of the current week :).

Answer (score 3):

Old question but if you're using rails you can now do the following to get next Friday.

```
Date.today.sunday + 5.days
```

Likewise you can do the following to get this Friday.

```
Date.today.monday + 4.days
```

Answer (score 2):

```
d = Date.new(2009, 11, 19)
d+=(5-d.wday) > 0 ? 5 - d.wday : 7 + 5 - d.wday
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails' [ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Date::Calculations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/files/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/date/calculations_rb.html) has methods that can help you.  If you're not using Rails, you could just require ActiveSupport.

Answer (score 1):

As Ruby's modulo operation (%) returns positive numbers when your divisor is positive, you can do this:

```
some_date = Date.new(2009, 11, 19)
next_friday = some_date + (5 - some_date.cwday) % 7
```

The only issue I can see here is that if `some_date` is a Friday, `next_friday` will be the same date as `some_date`.  If that's not the desired behavior, a slight modification can be used instead:

```
some_date = Date.new(...)
day_increment = (5 - some_date.cwday) % 7
day_increment = 7 if day_increment == 0
next_friday = some_date + day_increment
```

This code doesn't rely on additional external dependencies, and relies mostly on integer arithmetic.

Comment: Instead of doing an additional check, couldn't you just add one day to 'some_day' before applying your algo. date + 1 + (4 - date.cwday) % 7 works fine.